# Installing PECL UploadProgress on Mac 10.5.8

Tags: php, macos, osx-leopard, pecl

So, I have to develop an uploadprogress bar for a project. Thing is, host doesn't support it yet (communications will begin as soon as I have something I can show to my project leader).
So therefor I have to develop it locally.

I'm currently on a Mac G5 or something, the one with a PowerPC. So I'm running 10.5.8.

I've searched the net but can't really find anything that works.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [macports](http://www.macports.org/)? If so you may want to try `port install php5-uploadprogress`
Please be careful though.  Macports is a package manager for OS X and it does not use the default OS X php or apache or anything else.